# create vmware virtual machine via command line on linux system

Tags: command-line-interface, virtual-machines

evaluating/investigating vmware, and how you create a "virtual machine" using the command line for rhel/centos.

basically, i want to be able to create a test virtual machine and then be able to run the VM on another system using the virtual player.

so, i'm looking for pointers/articles/instructions that detail what i need (in terms of tools/apps) and the steps needed to accomplish this.

i've seen a few articles/sites that discuss creating virtual machines, but they all involve using the GUI.

thanks

update::

while vmware is the company. there are different tools/apps provided to create a Virtual Machine.

Basically, I want to do a test, to ultimately have a Virtual Machine/Image that can be run on a separate server using the vmplayer app

I've seen docs that discuss using the GUI to create the VM, but haven't found any (yet) that discuss how to accomplish this using the command line approach.

thanks...

Comment: vmware is a company not a product, what products are you talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/189861/create-a-guest-virtual-machine-from-command-line-in-vmware-esxi-vsphere-4

Answer (score 3):

In short do next in any linux box (RHEL/CentOS/etc) with installed qemu:

1. Create disk image file by `qemu-img create -f raw <image> <size (e.g. 4G)>`
2. Convert it to vmdk `qemu-img convert -f raw <qemu-image> -O <output_format> <vmplayer-image (.vmdk ext)>`
3. Create a .vmx file

Example:

Type in command line

```
qemu-img create -f raw /tmp/image.img 4G 
qemu-img convert -f raw /tmp/image.img -O vmdk /tmp/vmplayer-image.vmdk
```

And create **vmplayer.vmx** file (you can do this in Windows as well).

```
vi /tmp/vmplayer.vmx
```

Type **i** and insert next:

```
config.version = "8"
virtualHW.version = "3"
ide0:0.present = "TRUE"
ide0:0.filename = "vmplayer-image.vmdk"
memsize = "128"
MemAllowAutoScaleDown = "FALSE"
ide1:0.present = "TRUE"
ide1:0.fileName = "auto detect"
ide1:0.deviceType = "cdrom-raw"
ide1:0.autodetect = "TRUE"
floppy0.present = "FALSE"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
usb.present = "FALSE"
sound.present = "FALSE"
displayName = "some OS"
guestOS = "other26xlinux"
nvram = "someos.nvram"
MemTrimRate = "-1"
ide0:0.redo = ""
ethernet0.addressType = "generated"
ethernet0.connectionType = "nat"
uuid.location = "56 4d 0d 92 c9 cd 3c 25-c5 bf 91 91 43 5d bf 33"
uuid.bios = "56 4d 0d 92 c9 cd 3c 25-c5 bf 91 91 43 5d bf 33"
ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:0c:29:5d:bf:33"
ethernet0.generatedAddressOffset = "0"
tools.syncTime = "TRUE"
ide1:0.startConnected = "TRUE"
uuid.action = "create"
checkpoint.vmState = ""
tools.remindInstall = "TRUE"
```

Type **[Esc]:wq**

Or `guestOS = "winxppro"` for Win XP Pro

So you will need next files for VMWare Player:

- /tmp/vmplayer-image.vmdk
- /tmp/vmplayer.vmx

You can download them to Windows machine using [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php) util.

You will need to run **vmplayer.vmx** in VMWare Player.

Here [is complete guide](http://cri.ch/linux/docs/sk0020.html).

Comment: The command should be `qemu-img convert -f raw /tmp/image.img -O vmdk /tmp/vmplayer-image.vmdk` , or else there will be an error saying "qemu-img: Must specify image file name"

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about ESXi 4.x I don't know any ways to make a virtual machine not using the GUI. I know you can *copy* and *move* existing machines - or even deploy new ones from your 'gold' copy of your favorite OS.

If you're talking about using the VMware player, again just use the GUI - it was made for a reason and it seems to do its job well.

When you say "separate server using the vmplayer app" it sounds like you probably just want to install ESXi and run that... Please explain what you are trying to accomplish better.

Comment: hi. thanks for the reply. i want to create a clean OS (centos) on a given box/drive/partition. i then want to add some test apps to the "image". i then want to create a VM of the box/drive/partition. i then want to play/use this VM on a separate box, running the vmplayer app.    the reason for doing the VM creation using the command line, is that i want to programatically create the VM as the contents of the VM will change based on outputs of other apps.

Comment: You want VMConverter to make a P2V copy.  I'm unaware if there's a command-line interface to it.

Comment: yes the converter will take your physical machine and convert it into a virtual machine - but why do this when you can just make it in the hypervisor/'player'? I know you want to script but I think what you are trying to do isn't practical/not feasible with the current hypervisors that are on the market. Not to say you have a bad idea, just that it is a rare instance where you can be so general that you can script your configs...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a job for [vSphere CLI](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vcli/).

Unfortunately I haven't looked at this yet so I can't give you anything specific at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

In the file vmplayer.vmx

```
uuid.location = "56 4d 0d 92 c9 cd 3c 25-c5 bf 91 91 43 5d bf 33"
uuid.bios = "56 4d 0d 92 c9 cd 3c 25-c5 bf 91 91 43 5d bf 33"
```